# Some folder are not pushed to server when deployed to azure website in asp MVC using visual studio web deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

It seems that this problem is not popular that even stackoverflow has no post about it.

I just deployed my MVC 5 web site to Azure Web Site and found out that some of my custom folders are missing, not pushed to the server.

I tried to delete and create the same folder inside visual studio and then redeploy it again, but did not work.

I would like to know if there is a way to manually create a folder inside azure web sites directory? How do we actually edit the root directory manually? anything like control panel for azure web site file management?

Comment: Have you made sure that the folders or files contained within those folders are set to content and not none in the properties. Alternatively just right click the folder and click publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating empty folders in your code is super simple (I assume you're using C#):

```
string path = @"Path\To\Folder\You\Want";
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

If the directory already exists the CreateDirectory call won't do anything

Comment: Yep, I am using c#. oke I see now. Thanks @Zain

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Visual Studio exclude empty folders while deploying, so I have to put any file to those empty folders to make visual studio include them.

Comment: Or you could just create the folders in your code the first time you use them.  That would be a more hassle-free solution in the long run

Comment: "create the folders in your code"? it sounds pretty good, how can I actually do it?